# ImageMagick Magick++ is really slow to write gif

Tags: c++, multithreading, image, imagemagick

I wrote a simple C++ app using gdal and Magick++.
The program takes the tiff elaborated from Gdal and add it to a Magick gif.
The process is really slow and use around 800 MB of ram (with only 24 frames)... and takes 15 seconds
I tried to optimize the input files according to this http://im.snibgo.com/spdsiz.htm but the process still slow 
Im working for a part of a web service, so 15 second is really too much

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //timing for bench
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    char dirName[12];
    char timestamp[22];

    //takes the args and convert them to tm struct
    tm startDate = toTime(std::stringstream(argv[1]));
    tm endDate = toTime(std::stringstream(argv[2]));
    //calc the time differenze
    int diffHours = (int) std::difftime(timegm(&endDate), timegm(&startDate)) / 3600;
    //register gdal driver and create the datasets
    GDALAllRegister();
    GDALDataset *originalDataset;
    GDALDataset *newDataset;
    //option for the apply color to the tif file and set the alpha
    char *optionForDEM[] = {const_cast<char *>("-alpha"), nullptr};
    GDALDEMProcessingOptions *options = GDALDEMProcessingOptionsNew(optionForDEM, nullptr);

    //read the background and the "alert zones" (za)
    Magick::Image background;
    Magick::Image za;
    background.read("/home/giovanni/CLionProjects/MappeIRPI-CNR/sfondo2.mpc");
    za.read("/home/giovanni/CLionProjects/MappeIRPI-CNR/ZA.mpc");
    //create a vector for create the gif
    //i suspect that this method is really slow
    std::vector<Magick::Image> frames;


    int g;
    time_t date;
    for (int i = 0; i < diffHours; ++i) {
        //start of gdal processing block
        date = timegm(&startDate);
        strftime(dirName, 12, DIR_FORMAT.c_str(), gmtime(&date));
        fs::create_directory(fs::path(TEMP_PATH + dirName));

        originalDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen((BASE_PATH + dirName + PREVISTE).c_str(), GA_ReadOnly);
        newDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALDEMProcessing((TEMP_PATH + dirName + PREVISTE).c_str(),
                                                   originalDataset,
                                                   "color-relief",
                                                   COLORI.c_str(), options, &g);
        GDALClose(newDataset); //write the processed tif to ramdisk

        //start of the Magick++ block
        Magick::Image tif;
        //read the block
        tif.read(TEMP_PATH + dirName + PREVISTE);
        tif.scale(Magick::Geometry(1083, 1166));
        //add the background and the za
        //i want to apply that to the final gif, not to every single photo
        tif.composite(background, 0, 0, Magick::DstOverCompositeOp);
        tif.composite(za, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp);
        //options for annotate the frame
        tif.font("/usr/share/fonts/OTF/SFMono-Bold.otf");
        tif.fillColor("White");
        tif.fontPointsize(37);
        tif.boxColor("Black");
        strftime(timestamp, 22, DATE_FORMAT.c_str(), gmtime(&date));
        tif.annotate(timestamp, Magick::NorthEastGravity);
        //add the frame to the vector add set the animation delay
        frames.push_back(tif);
        tif.animationDelay(3000);

        startDate.tm_hour += 1;
    }

    //write the gif to disk, this takes a very long time
    Magick::writeImages(frames.begin(), frames.end(), TEMP_PATH + "sss.gif");

    GDALClose(originalDataset);
    GDALDEMProcessingOptionsFree(options);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << duration;

return 0;
}
```

This is the workflow:

- get the tifs
- do some work with gdal
- write the files as png (any faster format?)
- read the PNGs with .read
- annotate the images with the timestamp
- add the background and the ZA over the map *
- add the frame to the image vector
- write the vector

*i tryed to do this operation after collecting all images, avoiding doing it for each image, but I could not do it.

i tried to convert the background to a 2 colors png, and then to a miff file, and then to a mpc+cache one
the za.png uses alpha and 1 color, i did the same process

What are the fastest formats for the situation? I also need the gif to take as little as possible (it now occupies 5.4 MB !!)

As said the operation must be very fast so I can also consider other libraries simpler ... just fixed these basic problems will resort to multithread (any optimal method?) but from my tests the longest phase is the one that writes the gif on the disk (ramdisk above)

Sample of the result:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/6YVkqSMuoXwMYuE57

Google photo album:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/QDNCAK4i9PCGQW3VA

**EDIT**
Thanks for the quick comments

I'm on lates Arch linux, but the final program will run a web server not that powerfull
Debian 9.5, 4 virtual cores and 8 GB of ram (if necessary I can ask for an improvement, but not too much

have to manage a minimum of 24 frames but I could even get to 700 ...
the images initially take up 130KB but adding the arrival colors to 400KB
This before adding the background and dividing the zones (see the images in the google album)

i compile with G++ 8.2.1
this is the cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(MappeIrpi)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp vips.cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp -lstdc++fs")
add_executable(MappeIrpi ${SOURCE_FILES})
FIND_PACKAGE(GDAL COMPONENTS REQUIRED)
add_definitions(-DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=8)
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 )
add_definitions(-fopenmp -pthread)
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MappeIrpi ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES} gdal stdc++fs "/usr/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.6")
```

Currently I have not set optimization flags, but even setting -O3 or -Ofast does not change anything

resouce limits:

```
$ identify -list resource
 Resource limits:
  Width: 107.374MP
  Height: 107.374MP
  List length: -1
  Area: 33.4532GP
  Memory: 15.5779GiB
  Map: 31.1558GiB
  Disk: unlimited
  File: 15000
  Thread: 8
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

I will be grateful to anyone who helps me

Comment: Recommend only using the language tag for the compiler you're using. Tagging C for a question full of code that won't compile in C annoys people who are here to answer C questions. Maybe they can help you and maybe they'll simply downvote and move on. Hard to say which you'll get.

Comment: You posted absolutely no information on the compiler you're using, compiler optimization switches used to build the code, etc.  This information is just as, if not more important than what you are doing with the image itself.

Comment: It would help if you gave some indication of the dimensions of your images, the number of frames, whether there are many colours in the images, what OS, what CPU/RAM you have.

Comment: thanks now I add it

Comment: Can you profile this?  15 seconds is an eon on modern hardware.

Comment: It's rather difficult to help when your code has all the GDAL stuff in it and we don't have all your images. I think you might get on better if you started much more simply with, say 24, separate **representative** images and focus on making a GIF out of them as fast as possible. Failing that, I have seen issues with OpenMP slowing IM down, so you could try disabling that in your build. You could also try compiling with `-O3 -march=native` and running with `/usr/bin/time -l YourProgram` to check the RAM usage.

Comment: Also, check you have no restrictions on the resources you can use with `identify -list resource` in **Terminal**.

Comment: A lot of the code in your `for` loop can be optimized. You can also use `OpenMP` distribute the work across multiple CPUs.

Comment: Thanks, the question is how optimize It.